# Toggle a pseudo-element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to toggle the display of an `:after` pseudo-element (ie.to show/hide it) using jQuery. I successfully toggled the display of a div, but want to do this now with `:after`.

The `:after` is being used to create the arrow on the box.

My attempt can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/beechboy707/7um9knxt/1/

Here is an extract from it showing the jQuery which is supposed to relate to the CSS selector:

```
$("#supportus-button-1").click(function () {
$(".supportus-button:after").toggle();
});
```

Comment: This may be useful [Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after/21709814#21709814)

Comment: The term you're looking for is "pseudo-element". jQuery supports a selector syntax not unlike CSS, but it does not support pseudo-elements (as in the link above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest approach here is to use CSS classes to limit the scope where the `:after` rule is applied:

```
.supportus-button:not(.clicked):after { ... }
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjcwqjLw/

All [current browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) support the `:not` CSS feature: support [is the same](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) as for the `:after` pseudoelement.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. This worked and just added a display none and display block to reverse when the arrow showed.

Thanks also to @Salman-A for your equally valid answer!