# Issue: not able to change style to an event "click" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, events, click, styles

1)

- My goal is to change the style of a sound button after pushing a key ("a" in that case).
- After pushing "a" key, no style changement is made although I have built a CSS style linked to the event (by the class selector .button1) and there is sound. The function click() is working properly after pushing "a" (because: sound) but the style is not changing.
- No error message.

2)

- I have tried several things: .button1:active; .button:hover; put style within the JavaScript lines; creating a class for each event by adding classList.add('MyClass'); change the CSS selector (. or #).

3)

**HTML file**:

```
<button onclick="play1()" id="button1" class="button button1">A</button>

<script>
document.addEventListener("keydown", logKey);

            function logKey(){
                if (event.keyCode === 65) {
                    document.getElementById("button1").click();                 
                }
            }
</script>
```

**CSS file**:

```
.button1 {
    left: 400;
    bottom: 400;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: rgba(70, 96, 150, 0.6);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-radius: 20px;

}

.button1:active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    height: 122px;
    width: 122px;
}
```

Thanks.
PS: I do not use libraries/frameworks.

Comment: Your `logKey` function is `.click()`ing the button, but not changing its style, did you mean to change its style somewhere?

Comment: If you meant for the programmatic button press to result in the button being `:active`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630617/toggle-pseudo-class-active-with-css-jquery

Comment: @CertainPerformance When clicking to this button manually, it changes the style. So for me, creating a function that click() the button (mimicking the manual clicking) should also change the button style...?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there are any number of ways to implement this functionality in JS. Here is one that manually assigns a class when the `a` key is pressed. Note: this also results in the button having the `:active` pseudo-class when the function executes.

**Update**

Here's a bit more modular starting point you may want to try. Unfortunately, in vanilla JS, you can only assign one event listener at a time (unlike in jQuery, for example). That means we need two separate listeners: one for `keydown` and another for `keyup`. In my very simple example below, I'm commandeering your logKey function to just return whether or not the `event.keyCode` is equal to the key we're interested in (i.e., `a` | `65`). When logKey() returns a true value, we toggle the button's active class. It gets toggled on when the `keydown` event fires and toggled off when the `keyup` event fires.

I'm sure this isn't the most eloquent solution, but perhaps it will get you started down a useful path.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.button')
var KEY = 65;

var logKey = (event) => {
  return event.keyCode === KEY;
}

var toggleButton = function() { 
  let keyPressed = logKey(event);
  if (keyPressed) {
    button.classList.toggle('button--active');
  }
}
  
var listen = function() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', toggleButton);
  window.addEventListener('keyup', toggleButton);
}

listen();
```

```css
.button {
    left: 400;
    bottom: 400;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-radius: 20px;

}

.button--active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    height: 122px;
    width: 122px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" class="button">A</button>
```

**UPDATE 2**

> Moreover, is there a possibility to change the style directly within my function "logKey"?

Hmm. Directly with JavaScript? Sure. But I'd offload that responsibility to CSS. If you just mean apply a class within that function... possibly. Or, it could be that I'm misunderstanding you. The programmatic `click()` inside the logKey function just, well, programmatically clicks the button. But there still needs to be an function that executes on *click*.

Here's another option that may be more to your taste.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", logKey);
document.addEventListener("keyup", logKey);

var myButton = document.querySelector('#button');

function logKey(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 65) {
    myButton.click();
  }
}

function changeItUp() {
  myButton.classList.toggle('button--active');
};
```

```css
.button {
    left: 400;
    bottom: 400;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-radius: 20px;

}

.button--active,
.button:active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    height: 122px;
    width: 122px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeItUp()" id="button" class="button">A</button>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! However, the problem now is that the effect is remaining (i.e., once the a key pushed, the new style remains (.button--active) until the a key is pushed again). Moreover, is there a possibility to change the style directly within my function "logKey"?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do that. Not sure it is the best path forward, but I'll see what I can come up with if no one else provides a good solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button onclick="play1()" id="button1" class="button button1">A</button>
```

### Make sure .button1:active .button1+active

This will prevent the button from highlighting on right-click since "**:**" responds whenever the element is active.

```css
.button1+active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    height: 122px;
    width: 122px;
}
```

From the mousedown event the buttons property can be captured and whenever it's not a left click (*i.e. not equal to 1*) we return.

---

If the background on the other hand is not "rgb(76, 175, 80)" which is the rgb for "#4CAF50" then we add the color else we set the color to "".

```js
<script>
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", logKey);
  
  function logKey() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("button1")
    
    if ("buttons" in window.event && (window.event.target.id === "button1")) {
      if (window.event.buttons !== 1) {
        return
      } else {
        if (elem.style.backgroundColor !== "rgb(76, 175, 80)") {
          elem.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
        } else {
          elem.style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
      }
    }
  }
    
  function play1(){
    // console.log("elem")
  }  
  
</script>
```